# Order entries by month and year

Tags: orderby, sort

I need to order blog posts by year and month so the output would be someting like...

```
June 2013
Blog Title 1
Blog Title 2

May 2013
Blog Title 3
Blog Title 4

December 2012
Blog Title 5
```

How can I achieve this. Any help most appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [date_heading](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#date-heading).

```
{exp:channel:entries [...]}
    {date_heading display="monthly"}{entry_date format="%F %Y"}{/date_heading}
    [...]
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The value of the parameter "display" will set when the code on {date_heading} variable pair will be repeated.

Please, forgive the simple code sample, but you don't gave more details.

Comment: I will try that now. Thanks. I don't have enough rep to to Vote Up.

Comment: If you need more info, please improve your answer with a sample code.

Comment: As Robson said.. date_heading AND date_footer is the solution.. Then you can group by days, week, months, year..

Answer (score 2):

Using [Low Yearly Archives](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives), you can do something like that:

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="blog" status="not closed" sort="desc" monthsort="desc"}
    {months}
        {if num_entries != 0}
        <h2>{month} {year}</h2>
        <ul>
        {embed="news/archives_month" y="{year}" m="{month_num_short}"}
        </ul>
      {/if}
    {/months}
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}
```

And in your `archives_month` embed, something along those lines (we embed to get the parsing order for `{month_num_short}` right):

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog"
    disable="custom_fields|categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    dynamic="off"
    year="{embed:y}"
    month="{embed:m}"
    sort="asc"
}
<li><a href="{url_title_path=blog}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use "Low Yearly Archives" plugin. Find the doc from here http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives

Comment: Thanks. I tried Low Yearly Archives and was able to output by year and month but not pull out the actual blog posts. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Well, use Low Yearly Archive plugin to populate the years and month in descending order. Within it just put the channel entry tag with parameter year and month like year="{year}" and month="{month}".

Comment: month="{month}" results in all entries for the channel being displayed. What am I missing? If i hardcode e.g. month="2" it works, but how can I make it dynamic?