# Entries Grouped by month and year

Tags: channel-entries, entries, groups

I am looking to create a list page which will output all entries for a single year, but have them grouped by month. So for example i will have:

January
   entry A
   entry b
   entry c
February
   entry d
   entry e
   entry f

etc... The perfect solution would be like Lows Alphabet, but working on dates as opposed to starting letters... http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-alphabet

I cannot find any addons, or default functionality for this - and want to avoid running 12 entry queries! Therefore, i either have to code an addon, or php in the template to store and then output them how i want...

Does anyone know of an existing, elegant solution?
Or can give me guidance here - it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have enough "reputation" to comment, but what [I posted there](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/24331/1260) should answer the original question as well as the comment about the HTML formatting for the ULs.

Comment: After playing around with date_heading a little while, I found out that it always relates to the entry date (date on which you've submitted the entry). This was the show-stopper for me as I was trying to get the grouping done for a custom field. So with standard EE this is not possible

Answer (score 4):

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#date-heading

completely missed this before, but should make this more than possible.

---

EDIT

In response to the above comment, a better formatted view:

```
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}
{date_heading display="monthly"}
  <li>{entry_date format="%F"}
    <ul>
{/date_heading}
      <li>{title}</li>
{date_heading display="monthly"}
    </ul>
  </li>
{/date_heading}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you manage to get what you needed here? I'm wanting to output list items, grouped by Month, but can't think of how to break up the <ul> each time the {date_heading} tag outputs the month.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like something that Low Yearly Archive could be used for.

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archive